# Can I Call AHK Script From PHP or Javascript - Also How Do I Pass A Variable to a Script?

Tags: php, autohotkey, javascript

If I have an AHK script which has a variable in it - how can I pass a value to that variable so that the script runs with that value?

Can I call an AHK script from PHP or Javascript - if so how?  I ask this as it may be a solution to my first question (value passed when AHK script is called)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd, "Passing Command Line Parameters to a Script":

```
AutoHotkey.exe [Switches] [Script Filename] [Script Parameters]
```

So from any system which can execute commands, you would call the `autohotkey.exe` executable with the name of your script followed by your script's parameters (which will map them to variables like `%1`, `%2`, etc).

If you were using PHP to execute this, you might use [PHP's `shell_exec` command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('autohotkey script.ahk arg1 arg2');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Looks good - but where is the shell_exec directory?  I think that my script is not being found but I am guessing.

Comment: Thanks @ckhan - I can run my script from the command prompt but not from PHP which is my aim - I think that it is a directory problem - I do not know where to place my ahk script so that script_exec can find it (or which root to use so I can put the path in the scrip_exec command)

Comment: Sorted - thank you - your solution is perfectly correct - I am using EasyPhP as my PhP server - the script should have been in the root directory of the server - also I needed to use %1% rather than %1.